# Deleting a question that is borderline unanswerable

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, deleted-questions

[Why is my diplexer such a spectacular failure?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/16622/why-is-my-diplexer-such-a-spectacular-failure)

I feel that my original question was basically too broad. I'd like to break this diplexer problem into two questions, one concerning how to best use a simulator to analyze an RF circuit such as this diplexer, and another question that addresses best practices for interfacing a circuit on a PCB with coaxial I/O.

I also convoluted things by initially posting a circuit image that was incorrect..I apologize for this.

The Ham.SE community would benefit much more, I feel, from very specific and answerable questions regarding simulation and device construction/assembly.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your consideration for question quality!

However, to make sure others' work isn't wasted (the reason why self-deletion isn't allowed by the system in this case), I would recommend that you *first* ask the two new questions and then, *if* they get good answers, revisit the question of deleting the original.

That way, we're not worse off if the new questions don't attract great answers, and anyone answering the new one partly using material they wrote for the old one can easily retrieve it.

Comment: Got it...and yes, I appreciate so much the time and consideration taken by those who provided answers and in no way am trying to dismiss the valuable information within those answers. Ultimately, I'd love to see a series of questions and answers that if i had seen before I started building this thing, would have saved me some unnecessary trial and error, and provide a clear path for those who want to build one.